# angular6 phone number validation pattern

Tags: html, angular, validation

My input field is

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control"
       name="locphone"
       [(ngModel)]="locmodel.locphone"
       #locphone="ngModel"
       [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f2.submitted && locphone.invalid }"
       required
       locphone
       pattern="^\s*(?:\+?\d{1,3})?[- (]*\d{3}(?:[- )]*\d{3})?[- ]*\d{4}(?: *[x/#]\d+)?\s*$" />
```

Phone number should be in phone number format `999-999-9999`

Here how to change the pattern to support this format alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$
```

valid:

```
123-456-7890  
333-333-4444
```

invalid:

```
1234567890  
123456789  
123-4567-890  
14157059247
```

test: https://www.regextester.com/94189